# Where exactly the data-cy or data-test-id attribute to the element to test can be added?

Tags: cypress

I am a beginner for the Cypress automation testing. I have gone through the good practice document for Cypress E2E where it suggests to use `data-cy` or `data-test-id` for element selection. This might be a simple and dumb question but I am really curious to know the answer from you guys. I tried googling but no luck.

Where exactly the `data-cy` or `data-test-id` attribute to the element to test can be added?

a. Do I have to checkout the code from the developers team, then add the attribute in there?
b. Can I use the `invoke` command in cypress (just like we can add/remove attr using invoke in jquery)?
c. Any other method?

If the option a. is your answer, then
what are the steps you follow?
Does the app code and testing code need to be in one project?
What hierarchy of element selection you follow?

(More info: I have frontend in Typescript and React, backend in sql, test project in cypress)

Answer (score 16):

If `data-cy` or `data-test-id` attributes are not added to the elements in your project, you can not access the elements using these attributes.

Basically, it is a decision that team should take while developing front end application that all testable elements should have proper `data-cy` or `data-test-id` which gives more information about the element and it makes easy to write more stable and readable tests.

So I would suggest to discuss within a team to define strategy to add these attributes to the existing code and new code.

Read more about it at [best practices for selecting elements in cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements)

Comment: Thanks for addressing that @Krishna

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer. Thanks!